# Cannot create a new environment for Rust development using Docker Dev Environments

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, environment

[image: Screenshot of Docker, Git, Visual Studio Code and the Remote Containers Extension]

The overall context:
I'm following a tutorial in order to set up my own version of LegacyPlayersV3, which is a tool used to record logs about raid performance in an MMORPG, in this case, it's for WoW private servers (Warmane).
The Author of that tool has a Readme on his Github page, and i'm trying to get this whole thing to work.
The Readme is here: https://github.com/Geigerkind/LegacyPlayersV3#readme

So in order to achieve the goal, I need to get a program that's called Docker to work.
I enabled the Intel Virtualization Technology in my BIOS as required. I installed a couple other things which name i can't remember, but which were required as well and then i installed Docker.
It all went well.

I also installed Docker Compose.
Then i installed Rustup and its Nightly Toolchain (set to default), as instructed.

Now, the next line of instruction says : "**Go into the Environment directory** and start it using docker-compose -f docker-compose.mac_windows.yml up"

So i opened Docker, and clicked the big blue button that says : Create New Environment.
Another window popped asking me to install :

- Git (which i did)
- Visual Studio code and its Remote Containers Extention (which i also did)

You can see in the screenshot that I provided that I have my Docker window opened, as well as the VSC window and Git Bash. So it's all there, all installed, apparently functioning as it should.

And yet, for some reason, even though I installed everything Docker asks me to in order to create a new environment, I still cannot get passed that window...
I'm always stuck at 'Make sure you have your tools installed!"
I tried restarting the program, restarting my computer. I checked multiple times if Git and VSC worked properly, and they do seem to work properly, so really I'm stuck at this point.
I looked over this particular issue over the internet, but couldn't find anything.

Would anyone have any idea as to why I can't get passed that window?

I tried restarting the program.
I checked multiple times that the other required programs are functionning properly.
I looked up this particular issue on Google, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

"Go into the environments directory" means opening a terminal window. Usually that's called Command Prompt on Windows, but AFAIK PowerShell should work, too.
Using the `cd` (Change Directory) command followed by the path where you cloned the repository will get you to the right path. Alternatively you might be able to right click on the directory in Explorer and choose "Command Prompt here" or similar - no idea whether that's available in a regular Windows installation.

Afterwards, the command `docker-compose -f docker-compose.mac_windows.yml up` needs to be run from that command prompt.
Then you'll need to open additional command prompts for the backend and frontend directories and run the respective commands listed in the README so that all components are running at the same time.